# How to Initialize a django form with values from a model

Tags: python, django

I am making a shopping website, I am trying to initialize my products update form with the product information but I cant get the information from the model into the form.

models function

```
def get_product_details(product_id):
    product_details = Products.objects.filter(name=rproduct_id).select_related('name', 'description','price','qty')
    return product_details
```

form.py

```
class UpdateProductForm(forms.Form):

        name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        required=True,
        label="* name:",
        widget=TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'span6 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'}),
    )
        description = forms.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        required=True,
        label="* description:",
        widget=TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'span6 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'}),
    )
        price = forms.IntegerField(
        label="* price:",
        widget=TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'span6 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'}),
    )
        qty = forms.IntegerField(
        label="* Qty:",
        widget=TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'span6 small-margin-top small-margin-bottom'}),
    )
```

view.py

```
def update_risk(request,product_id):

    product_details = get_product_details(product_id)


    name = form.cleaned_data['name'] 
    description = form.cleaned_data['description']
    price = form.cleaned_data['price']
    qty = form.cleaned_data['qty']

    form = UpdateProductForm(product_details)



    return render(
        request,
        template_name = 'products/forms/update_product_form.html',
        dictionary = {
            'form':form,
            'instr_text':instr_text
        }
    )
```

update form

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'products:update'%}">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.name }}
{{ form.description }}
{{ form.price }}
{{ form.qty }}
</form>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)? It handles a large portion of the form processing for you if you are just updating a model. Also, `select_related` only helps if you are selecting relationships - looks like you are selecting non-relational fields.

Comment: I am only getting fields from one table

Comment: no I am new to django I have not looked at the updateview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use ModelForms, which are designed not only to match the fields of the model, but also can easily be initialized with the data from a model.

See here for a general description: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/

Specifically, if the form is a ModelForm, you can do this:

```
>>> article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```